# Using QGIS OpenStreetMap Plugin and tags

Tags: openstreetmap, qgis-plugins

I'm using QGIS and the OpenStreetMap Plugin to manage osm files.

That plugin is very useful, but limited to a few tags that will be converted into dbf file.

I'm looking for a method allowing to add some tags or rename existing in order to manage them easily in the dbf file.

I've searched for the author of this plugin, but no one came out.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get the tags you want is by using osm2pgsql and a PostGIS database. You can define the tags you want to import as columns in the default.style file.

I dont't know if that works on Mac OSX.

From the PostGIS database, you can make queries, and save them as shapefiles. Those shapefiles can be altered with the table manager to get rid of the attributes you don't want.

A simpler way would be the OSM tools for SpatiaLite:

https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite-tools/wiki?name=OSM+tools